# Can't encrypt a non-system drive in-place with VeraCrypt

Tags: windows, hard-drive, encryption, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I've just started using VeraCrypt and used it to encrypt my system drive (Windows 10) with no problems - however, I wanted to also do this to my main storage drive, on which the system does not reside. However, every time I try to do it, I get informed that it cannot be dismounted and whether I want to force dismount - which I agree to but still, I just get an error reading that it failed.

I've read some tips online and some of them recommended unchecking Windows's file indexing on that drive which I did but it didn't help at all. I have a hunch that the problem lies in a weird interdependence between the drives in my case - the "system" drive basically holds only the system and the things that would benefit from being on an SSD; the partition I'm trying to encrypt, however, holds a lot of other programs (some of which are probably running in the background) and symbolic links from the system drive point to some of the places there, too. I've tried using the Process Explorer to kill off the processes that appear when searching for `D:\` and was able to narrow it down to:
[image]

Which is basically only Bitdefender, the Process Explorer itself and system stuff - and I see no real way to reduce it further. This allowed me to get *a little* further in the encrypting process (it now takes ~15 minutes during which is goes through the "expanding" status before it breaks while on the "preparing" status) but still to start the encryption itself is impossible. I've tried turning off Bitdefender through its GUI but to no avail.

What should I do in this case? Can I somehow encrypt it without running the full system - like from some command line without the need to run Windows itself or in safe mode? How should I progress in this case if I'd like to encrypt the drive in place?

EDIT: As per @Ramhound suggestion, I've tried disabling all Bitdefender services using their [guide](https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/13426/) and managed to shrink the process list to one like this (even with Bitdefender theoretically turned off completely, these three processes still stay):
[image]
This allowed me to progress further in the process, ie. I did not get the error reading that it can't unmount the drive anymore but what I *did* get was an error reading that it cannot shrink the filesystem - I defragmented the drive like it suggested, analyzed like it said too but to no avail. I have 120GB free on the partition (out of 1TB total) so it's hardly full...

Comment: Have you considered disabling whatever BitDefender is doing to protect the drive in question?

Comment: @Ramhound - thanks, tried that just now - edited the details into the question but long story short, it didn't help either, just changed the error I'm getting from "cannot unmount" to "cannot shrink filesystem" :(